# How can I have ruler for a `RadRichTextBox`

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have the following code in `xaml`

```
<telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="radRichTextBox" IsSelectionMiniToolBarEnabled="False" IsSpellCheckingEnabled="False" IsContextMenuEnabled="False" LayoutMode="Paged" Margin="10,192,10,10"/>
```

How can I add ruler for a `RadRichTextBox` in telerik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<telerik:DocumentRuler DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="10">
    <telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="radRichTextBox" IsSelectionMiniToolBarEnabled="False" IsSpellCheckingEnabled="False" IsContextMenuEnabled="False" LayoutMode="Paged" />
</telerik:DocumentRuler>
```